Hole in Hollow Wooden Door
My husband slipped in our hallway and his elbow went through the hollow, wood(?) door of our guest bathroom. The hole is pretty small and I am wondering if there are any decent repair kits that could fix this (I’m willing to get a texturizer and whatever else to make it look legit).
If not, I have found this replacement door but am unsure if it will work. The finish looks slightly different. Any idea what I should be searching instead to get closer? I am seeing things like “masonite” and “smooth flush” and don’t really know what’s correct because it is smooth, but it does have tiny grooves.
Option 1
I would just leave it to my landlord to handle (and ultimately will if I have to) but they are the type to try and take the whole deposit ($5K!) for something like this and I don’t feel like going the small claims route with them in the future to dispute it.
Any advice is appreciated even if it’s to just cut my losses!
Pics included as reference to understand the size and finish.
Pics
Thank you so much for any and all advice.

If it were your own door, I'd suggest putting up some decoration to cover it, but I doubt that a DIY patch will satisfy the landlord. You might make clear to the owner what happened, and come to an agreement beforehand... or not.

There is no repairing that door, sorry.
You need to look for a luan slab hollow core door in the size you have.
Luan is the common type of skin on the damaged door. Do not buy masonite.
You may need to stain to match the old color, or just use some clear. That is often the method used when putting doors in rental units.
You may need to order it but luan slabs are available and if you can, get one that is pre bored for the knob and lockset. ( In most cases the position is standard. take some measurements with you when you go to purchase.)
You do not need pre-hung. A handyman can help with the install if you are not comfortable doing it.

Any luan skins available?  A skin and contact cement would cover that hole/door.   Maybe cheaper than a new door.

A good thought, but the door would be thicker and closing would become the new problem.

Moving the door stops back a bit(depending which side of door) is not that hard.  Maybe an extra 5 minutes for the fix.  Talking about 1/8 to 3/16 inch.

If you can pull the 3 stops and reinstall with the door striker moved as well and all the paint done properly in 5 minutes. I need you to come here to fla. I have a month of work for you to do in 3 days.

It seems OP's husband hit the outside skin of the door.  Do you not paint/stain the door frame before putting on the door stops?

@crip, yes and moving them will leave obvious scars.  It's not a 5 min job unless you want it to look like a 10 year old did it.

If you have a good door shop nearby, they could take your old door and exactly match size, hinge mortises and knob bore. Then reinstall is easy.
